# Each button value show in circle progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar

I need to made for each button in my panel to get it's value and make a progress bar for it.

[This](https://codepen.io/srph/pen/xwxKoN) is the progress bar I want.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQFIZ.jpg) is how the panel currently looks like.

Following with the code of the panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="contLine13" runat="server" CssClass="simexContainers" BorderWidth="1px" Style="position: relative">
  <asp:Panel ID="LINEA13" runat="server" CssClass="simexTitles">
    <asp:Label ID="lblLine1" runat="server" Text="Linea 1" />
  </asp:Panel>
  <div id="jednatrecina" style="width: 33%; float: left; margin-top: 100px;">
    <asp:Button ID="btn17" runat="server" CssClass="stolovi" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="5" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn18" runat="server" CssClass="stolovi" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="5" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn19" runat="server" CssClass="stolovi" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="5" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn20" runat="server" CssClass="stolovi" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="5" />
  </div>
  <div id="dvetrecine" style="width: 66%; float: right;">
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="1" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn9" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="1" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <hr style="width: 75%;" />
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn10" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn11" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn4" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn12" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn5" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn13" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn6" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="3" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceKruzic">
      <asp:Button ID="btn14" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceKruzicBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="2" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <hr style="width: 75%;" />
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn7" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="4" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn15" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" AccessKey="3" />
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn8" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" />
    </span>
    <span class="KoferceCircle">
      <asp:Button ID="btn16" runat="server" CssClass="KoferceBox" OnClick="buttons_click" />
    </span>
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No console errors, So in this progress bar I have one .svg, css and js. I don't know how to made it for each button